# Service not available in the controller's container and cannot replace it from Listener

Tags: symfony

I am porting a custom bundle that was created originally for symfony 2 to Symfony 5. 
Inside the bundle there is a listener with this function:

```
public function onEarlyKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
{
    if (!$tenant = $this->tenantStrategy->getTenant()) {
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch($tEvent = new TenantEvent(null, $event), TenantEvents::TENANT_NOT_FOUND);
        if (!$tEvent->getTenant()) {
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new TenantEvent($tenant, $event), TenantEvents::TENANT_FOUND);

    //$this->container->set('synd_multitenant.tenant', $tenant);
}
```

When I remove the comment from the last line I get this error:
The "synd_multitenant.tenant" service is already initialized, you cannot replace it.
With that line commented out, When I try to get the service from the controller I get this message:

```
Service "synd_multitenant.tenant" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\DefaultController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.
```

And in case it is relevant, I had to change to RequestEvent from GetResponseEvent because GetResponseEvent is not supported anymore.
Here is the controller where I am trying to use the service:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Repository\ClientRepository;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController {

    function index() {
        //$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //$clientRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('App\Entity\Client');
        //$client = $clientRepository->findOneBy(array('domain' => 'someclient.mysymfony.local'));

        $client = $this->get('synd_multitenant.tenant');

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Welcome to My Symfony 5 demo!'.
            '<br>Client: ' . $client->getDomain() .
            '</body></html>'
            );
    }

}
```

Here is the output of console debug:

```
$ php bin/console debug:container synd_multitenant.tenant

Information for Service "synd_multitenant.tenant"
=================================================

 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                          
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       synd_multitenant.tenant                        
  Class            Synd\MultiTenantBundle\Entity\TenantInterface  
  Tags             -                                              
  Public           yes                                            
  Synthetic        no                                             
  Lazy             no                                             
  Shared           yes                                            
  Abstract         no                                             
  Autowired        yes                                            
  Autoconfigured   yes                                            
 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------
```

The complete code is available at this github repository: https://github.com/karimmtl/Mysymfony5

Thanks

Comment: Always fun to look at old code.  $container->set has not worked in a very long time.  Kind of surprised it ever did.  Creating a tenant requires request information.  Maybe some sort of a TenantFactory combined with a factory service definition to be able to inject the tenant.  I'm sure the original developer had good reasons for what they did but it sure looks convoluted.

Comment: @Cerad, Thank you for your comment. When I read 'convoluted' I started to lough. All the time I was debuging and fixing I was saying that to myself. It feels good to have the same feedback from somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

found out that the tentant service class name is

> \Synd\MultiTenantBundle\Entity\TenantInterface

in the bundles service.yaml file.

Try to change your controller so that you inject the service:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Repository\ClientRepository;
use Synd\MultiTenantBundle\Entity\TenantInterface;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController 
{

    function index(TenantInterface $client) 
    {
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Welcome to My Symfony 5 demo!'.
            '<br>Client: ' . $client->getDomain() .
            '</body></html>'
            );
    }

}
```

Comment: it didn't work. Here is the error that I got: Cannot autowire argument $client of "App\Controller\DefaultController::index()": it references interface "Synd\MultiTenantBundle\Entity\TenantInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "synd_multitenant.tenant" service.

Comment: if you debug the container on the CLI could you find the service?

Comment: I added the ouput from console debug:container to the original question. I also commented out autowire and autoconfigure section, but it still does not work.

Comment: @FrankB - If you look at the code you will see that it is a 'fake' service.  The instance itself is created in a listener and then added to the container.  You used to be able to do this back in Symfony 2.0.  But no longer. So no matter how you tweak things, your answer will not work.

Comment: i see Cerad. Never seen that before... Know a solution for the TS?